# forcing single quotes on XMLout()

Tags: perl, xml-simple

Is there an easy way to force `XMLout()` of `XML::Simple` to use single quotes instead of double quotes for the attributes? I didn't find an according option (or I missed it...).

```
<Object Alias="12345" Inherit="1" Position="0">
```

should be

```
<Object Alias='12345' Inherit='1' Position='0'>
```

It's just a matter of conventions, no special reason for that. Also there won't be any conflict with inner quotes because they are all escaped.

Answer (score 0):

why you want to do this? i dunno any good reason where it can be useful?! you can print your xml file with xml out and open it again doing `while(<>){s/\"/\'/g;}`

Comment: It's just a style convention. And I wanted to avoid to reopen it and write it again.